# How can I open .jar for modding?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I go to `C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.6.2`, I see my .jar file but when I try to open it, it does nothing. So how do I open my .jar file so I can mod it? I also know that if I extract the files my minecraft crashes. Why is that? How can I open it so I can mod it?

Comment: How do you open it? Do you double-click it, or right click > Open with > Editor?

Comment: @5pike Not always possible. Most jar files do not have editable code in it, but precompiled one to save you time when compiling your project. Then there is again the difference between access to the jar file's functions and methods and a pure executable jar file. To Raymond Green: I think most people take the byte code which is interpreted by the Java virtual machine and from there on decompile the jar file into somewhat readable code. Problem beeing that classes,variables, etc are not named as in the original code. This is just an educated guess though, so I'm not posting this as an answer.

Comment: Also, I think this question might be better answered by gamedev.stackexchange.com as it deals with a game-specific programming issue.

Comment: @strike No, they're not trying to create mods (you can't do that by opening the jar). They're trying to install mods as an end user.

Answer (score 5):

you use any package manager that can handle a zip, because a jar is a zip with a different extension, the jar is signed though so you'll need to remove the files in META-INF when you repackage

however I suggest you look at [forge](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Main_Page); this is an api to make modding easier and allows compatibility between mods

Comment: [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) is a good one.

Comment: @Dillmo Or WinRar.